# How to insert Data into sql server database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to insert data into my SQL Server 2014 database, but I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

My table matches the types of data I put in, for example, I'm put an `int` into a `int`.

Here is my code:

```
string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
string name = "Jesus said: Love your Enemies (V.S.)";

int blueq = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
int redq = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
int whiteq = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
int blackq = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text);
int whiteqr = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox9.Text);
int redqr = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox10.Text);
int sn = 600;
int price = total_jslye;

string size; 

if (RadioButton1.Checked == false)
{
    size = "11x35";
}
else
    size = "18x50";

try
{
    string conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLCS"].ConnectionString;
    var cmd = "INSERT INTO cartsigns (@SignNumber, @redquantity, @bluequantity, @whitequantity, @blackquantity, @whitereflectivequantity, @redreflectivequantity, @size, @SignName, @ipaddress, @price)";

    using (SqlConnection com = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(cmd, com))
        {
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SignNumber", sn);
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@redquantity", redq);
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bluequantity", blueq);
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whitequantity", whiteq);
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blackquantity", blackq);
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whitereflectivequantity", whiteqr);
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@redreflectivequantity", redqr);
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", size);
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SignName", name);
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ipaddress", ip);
            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);

            com.Open();
            cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }  
    }
}
```

So please help, thanks

Comment: good post, for best results with your questions, make sure you clarify your question in the body of your post along with adding a few examples of things you tried. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I never tried to do it, but I think you cannot declare parameters with [...], try to remove spaces and declare them like @SignNumber without spaces

Comment: Why don't you do it the standard way? Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) and read the example at the end.

Comment: See the rules for naming identifiers [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

Comment: remove spaces in the parameter and try

Comment: "I mean ... *really?!"*  :-/  This is quite-obviously nothing more than "a case where a language-compiler has fallen off-the-bus."  *You* made a syntax-error.  The compiler detected the error shortly after it parsed the token `int`, and as a result it threw a "throw-away error message" *(which actually makes no sense at all)*. Compilers do such things all the time. I can spot the syntax-error from here. . .

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter names can not have brackets or spaces in them in SQL Server.  So rename them all to @SignNumber, @redquantity, @bluequantity... etc.

Comment: OK that helped, I got rid of all spaces and brackets in both the DB and my website. But it has the same error but says ")" instead of "int". Any Ideas?

Comment: I think you should update your question with the current code. Have you triple-checked all the parenthesis?

Comment: you are missing the keyword values in your insert statment.          var cmd = "INSERT INTO cartsigns VALUES (@SignNumber,@redquantity,@bluequantity,@whitequantity,@blackquantity,@whitereflectivequantity,@redreflectivequantity,@size,@SignName,@ipaddress,@price)";

Answer (score 5):

Your insert syntax is not correct. you have not given column names also keyword "Values" is missing in your query

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. you will get your desired result. The issue that you were getting in your code is because parameters are not supposed to have any spaces or brackets or any characters that makes the parameter names not well formed. A parameter name must begin with "@" character, and should follow the rules for object identifiers. Check the [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177436%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for further details.

```
    string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
    string name = "first sign";
    int blueq = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
    int redq = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
    int whiteq = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
    int blackq = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text);
    int whiteqr = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox9.Text);
    int redqr = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox10.Text);
    int sn = 600;
    int price = total_jslye;


    string size; 
    if (RadioButton1.Checked == false)
    {
        size = "11x35";
    }
    else
        size = "18x50";

        try
        {
            string conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLCS"].ConnectionString;




            var cmd = "INSERT INTO cartsigns ([Sign Number],[red quantity],[blue quantity],[white quantity],[black quantity],[white reflective quantity],[red reflective quantity],[size],[Sign Name],[ipaddress],[price]) values (@[Sign_Number],@[red_quantity],@[blue_quantity], @[white_quantity],@[black_quantity],@[white_reflective_quantity],@[red_reflective_quantity],@[size],@[Sign_Name],@[ipaddress],@[price])";

            using (SqlConnection com = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(cmd, com))
                {
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Sign_Number]", sn);
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[red_quantity]", redq);
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[blue_quantity]", blueq);
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[white_quantity]", whiteq);
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[black_quantity]", blackq);
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[white_reflective_quantity]", whiteqr);
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[red_reflective_quantity]", redqr);
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[size]", size);
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Sign_Name]", name);
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[ipaddress]", ip);
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[price]", price);


                    com.Open();
                    cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```